# LibreOffice and HSQLDB SERVER: cannot access with my Windows Notebook on the HSQLDB Server running on iMAC OSX Sierra

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice, openoffice, macos-sierra

I have used so far the OpenOffice and now LibreOffice package with the standard BASE System, so the HyperSQL DB in Embedded Mode and have to say, it is quiet easy using it on one computer.
However my ambition is to bring my database towards a multi-user system where more people can access simultaniously onto the HSQLDB Server for recording and reading datasets. I want that it runs inside my home network (via a LINK Switch).
I already understood how to exract the ODB file and to use and access the single files. Pity that it is not directly implemented in LibreOffice and it makes the world later more difficult..
I also installed the HyperSQL (newest version 2.4.0) on my Apple iMAC, running now with the latest OS SIERRA, and the server mode is running great without any problems.
However I cannot access with my notebook on the server to open the database.
On the iMAC I have the following line in the LibreOffice and works:
jdbc: hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
I have used the test database from the HyperSQL Manual and use the mydb file but for public it uses xdb.
The JDBC driver is also working as I can access:  org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
I have learned that it is important to write the JDBC Driver correctly with small and capital letters, otherwise there is an error message and you won´t be able to go forward.

On my Windows Notebook I use the following URL and cannot get any connection with the following trials:
1.)   jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://192.168.1.104/xdb
2.)   jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://192.168.1.104/Programme/hsqldb-2.4.0/hsqldb/lib/mydb respective I also tried with xdb
But LibreOffice cannot establish any connection.
Why?

I tried to access since a whilte to the HyperSQL Server from another device but still it does not work.
I would be very happy if someone out there could help me.

Many thanks in advance for all the helpful people.

Vincent